# Saber se valor de determinado índice de array multidimensional é sempre vazio

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Tenho um array multidimensional resultante de uma consulta ao banco de dados e gostaria de saber se um índice é sempre vazio (mas não quero excluí-lo).
No exemplo de array abaixo, `$meuArray[$chave][3]` é sempre vazio.

```
$meuArray = Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
        [0] => "Item 1"
        [1] => "Setor 1"
        [2] => "Filial 1"
        [3] => 
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
        [0] => "Item 2"
        [1] => "Setor 1"
        [2] => 
        [3] =>
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
        [0] => "Item 3"
        [1] => "Setor 2"
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        )
)
```

Comment: Mas qual sua dúvida especificamente? Quer consultar se essa posição é vazia ou quer gerar um espécie de tabela?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

De modo bem simplório você pode implementar algo dessa forma **Caso a estrutura do array for sempre exatamente igual a esse que mencionou** :

```
<?php

function verificaIndiceVazio(array $dados, $index = 0): bool
{
    if (is_null($index) || !is_int($index)) {
        throw new Exception('Index a ser avaliado não foi informado!');
    }
    $tamanhoArray = count($dados);
    $indicesVazios = 0;
    foreach ($dados as $valor) {
        foreach ($valor as $chave => $dado) {
            if ($index && $chave == $index) {
                $indicesVazios = empty($dado) ? ++$indicesVazios : $indicesVazios;
            }
        }
    }
    return $indicesVazios === $tamanhoArray;
}
```

Você pode passar array e o índice por parâmetro

```
verificaIndiceVazio($meuArray, 3);
```

Passei com o código não tão enxuto, para mostrar a lógica de pegar o tamanho do array, acessar o primeiro subnível, etc. *Caso queira otimizar o código, fique à vontade*

**Agora, SE** o seu array tiver outra estrutura *Com mais subníveis* recomedo que consulte a documentação do [Array Walk Recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-walk-recursive.php) <- aqui você trabalha com array multidimensional de forma recursiva, utilizando uma função callback para manipular e verificar os dados se desejar.

*Você pode incluir uma validação para tratar se o usuário passar um index que não existe no array*

Comment: Compreendi e funcionou  corretamente. Procurei por algo mais direto como um `array_search()`, mas dessa forma ficou bastante didático também.

Comment: Gomes, acabei de ver que fecharam meu tópico e ainda colocaram tua resposta como não útil. No geral, a comunidade brasileira desse site me desagrada demais. Qualquer coisa é motivo para fecharem o tópico e 'negativarem'. A comunidade americana, por mais boba que seja minha pergunta, nunca fiquei sem respostas.

Comment: Fique tranquilo! Cada um tem sua capacidade técnica e ponto!
Algumas pessoas mais capacitadas e outras menos, e tá tudo bem. A área de tecnologia mexe muito com ego, e deixamos um pouco a necessidade do outro de lado para "vomitarmos" nossas habilidades em cima dos outros.
Não estou me importando com a "gamificação" da plataforma, estou focado em aprender, tentar de alguma forma ajudar e só. Olhando e tentando resolver a dúvida das pessoas, você ajuda quem tem a necessidade e acaba se ajudando fortalecendo um aprendizado. Se deu certo, lhe serviu a resposta, é o que importa.

Comment: Pode ser que não seja no momento o código mais performático, curto e objetivo, mas cada um tem seu tempo, e aos poucos vamos melhorando! Sim temos esse "problema" aqui no BR. Mas, foque no que realmente importa: Resolver o problema, aprender e se desenvolver (sem julgamento alheio). Lembre-se que as Soft Skills também são muito importantes!